# Scaling Kafka Message Consumption with multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka

Does implementing multi-threading in receiving Kafka messages help to handle many messages?
For instance, I want to do some high latency message processing, and I'm wondering if I should implement multi-threads to handle the message processing.
Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

It's not so much clear to me what you want to achieve but consider this. The scaling on the consumer side is reachable through having more partitions in the topic and more consumers in the same consumer group so that you can parallelize getting messages from different partitions with  different consumers (the maximum parallelism is done with partitions equals number of consumers). Then, inside each consumer, because getting messages from partition is done through a poll() inside a loop, you can of course get the messages from the poll and putting them inside an internal buffer and having a threads pool to process them in parallel (if ordering doesn't matter for you) and leaving the main thread to poll() again for getting new messages. Related to the order, you have to pay attention to the commit phase because processing messages out of order means committing offset out of order as well.